# Validate SSH host key format in Java

Tags: java, regex, ssh, ssh-keys

is there a nice way to validate format/pattern of a [SSH Host Key](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key)?

I've seen some guys doing it with regex like this one to validate RSA:

```
^(ssh-[a-z]{3}) ([0-9]{3,4}) ([0-9a-f]{2}:){15}[0-9a-f]{2}$
```

Or use a parser like [this](https://pypi.org/project/sshpubkeys/) on Python.

Can you guys help with **dsa**/**ecdsa** and **ed25519** regex?

I didn't founded a nice parser to do it by Pythonic way on Java :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`KnownHosts` class](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KnownHosts.java.html) from [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).